# Text styling in QTableView with PySide2

Tags: python, qtableview, pyside2

I have a QTableView populated with a proper model.
I would like to change the style of the text based on the context of it:

The text, if there is something between parenthesis, just this part of text should change to green color -parenthesis included- (and bold, just if it is not harder).

If you can provide a snippet or super simple example, I appreciate it.

Comment: from what I understand you want the text that is in parentheses plus the parentheses change to green or bold and the rest do not change, am I right?

Comment: yes, exactly, thanks!! Green, or green and bold, but not just bold.

Comment: So, be direct in your question and do not give it many laps

Comment: @eyllanesc, Now that is simple and direct, could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a delegate that uses `QTextDocument`:

```
import random
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

words = '''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Mauris euismod cursus mi sit amet pellentesque. 
Proin sed lectus sed augue scelerisque congue eget quis leo. 
Curabitur ultrices nisi nisi, placerat gravida urna sagittis et. 
Nullam vitae urna tortor. Curabitur a lobortis metus, et laoreet arcu. 
Quisque a mi in purus molestie porta non sit amet purus. 
Sed porta non purus et suscipit.'''.split()

class HighlightDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(HighlightDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self.doc = QtGui.QTextDocument(self)
        self._regex = QtCore.QRegularExpression()
        self._highlight_format = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        painter.save()
        options = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
        self.initStyleOption(options, index)
        self.doc.setPlainText(options.text)
        self.apply_highlight()
        options.text = ""
        style = QtWidgets.QApplication.style() if options.widget is None \
            else options.widget.style()
        style.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, options, painter)

        ctx = QtGui.QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext()
        if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected:
            ctx.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, option.palette.color(
                QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText))
        else:
            ctx.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, option.palette.color(
                QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text))

        textRect = style.subElementRect(
            QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemText, options)

        if index.column() != 0:
            textRect.adjust(5, 0, 0, 0)

        the_constant = 4
        margin = (option.rect.height() - options.fontMetrics.height()) // 2
        margin = margin - the_constant
        textRect.setTop(textRect.top() + margin)

        painter.translate(textRect.topLeft())
        painter.setClipRect(textRect.translated(-textRect.topLeft()))
        self.doc.documentLayout().draw(painter, ctx)

        painter.restore()

    def apply_highlight(self):
        cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(self.doc)
        cursor.beginEditBlock()
        highlightCursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(self.doc)
        while not highlightCursor.isNull() and not highlightCursor.atEnd():
            highlightCursor = self.doc.find(self.regex, highlightCursor)
            if not highlightCursor.isNull():
                highlightCursor.mergeCharFormat(self.highlightFormat)
        cursor.endEditBlock()

    @property
    def regex(self):
        return self._regex

    @regex.setter
    def regex(self, regex):
        if self._regex == regex: return
        self._regex = regex

    @property
    def highlightFormat(self):
        return self._highlight_format

    @highlightFormat.setter
    def highlightFormat(self, fmt):
        self._highlight_format = fmt

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()

        self._delegate = HighlightDelegate(self.table)
        self._delegate.regex = QtCore.QRegularExpression(r"\(.*?\)")
        fmt = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        fmt.setForeground(QtCore.Qt.green)
        fmt.setFontWeight(QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        self._delegate.highlightFormat = fmt
        self.table.setItemDelegate(self._delegate)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(10, 4)
        for i in range(model.rowCount()):
            for j in range(model.columnCount()):
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem("{}({}){}".format(*random.sample(words,3)))
                model.setItem(i, j, item)
        self.table.setModel(model)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: @eyllanesc ... I am trying to convert your example to pyqt4... any help would be very appreciated. :)

Comment: @panofish python2 or python3?

Comment: @eyllanesc .. python2... I also updated your other example where I attempted to convert [https://stackoverflow.com/a/57064002/259538](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57064002/259538)

Comment: @panofish I have already added the version for PyQt4, later I will also add a similar version for this answer.

Comment: @eyllanesc .. you are my hero.  The PyQt4 version works great!